# Об аббревиатурах

Tags: орфография, аббревиатуры

Как правильнее писать: ВДВшник, ВДВ-шник или вэдэвэшник? Или, например, СС-овец (но тогда какие-то "овцы" получаются) или эсэсовец?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово **эсэсовец** (в таком написании)зафиксировано словарями, употребляется во многих художественных произведениях и пишется слитно. Слово вэдэвэшник - разговорное, в словарях его еще нет. Можно предположить, что по аналогии оно может быть тоже написано слитно. Но необязательно. ЗАкон аналогии работает не всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Да напишите в конце-концов "солдат (офицер) ВДВ". Я думаю, что это беспроигрышный вариант. Зачем употреблять "ВДВшник" и варианты, если не уверены в корректности?

Касательно что лучше из вариантов "ВДВшник" и "ВДВ-шник", то я однозначно за первый. Не должно быть дефиса.